# Is it safe to perform file-based (fd-based) access on a POSIX shared memory object?

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix, shared-memory

`shm_open` returns an `fd` associated with a "shared memory object". And normally, this object is then mapped into virtual memory (with `mmap`) to access as a `memory-mapped file`.

**However**, is it safe to access the shared memory object **through its `fd`** (as if it were a normal file)? And by "safe", I mean guaranteed by POSIX to have well-defined behavior?

The reason I'm asking is that I'm working with a third-party interface that will **only** accept an `fd` (instead of a memory address) for writing a fixed number of bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  [POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html):

> If `fildes` refers to a shared memory object, the result of the
>   `write()` function is unspecified.

..and the same for `read()`.

It does work on Linux, though, where a shared memory object is a file backed by the `tmpfs` filesystem.